# Get JSON data from instagram api and extract text between specific keyword

Tags: php, json, instagram

Im trying to get data from instagram comment API,
example URL: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/375163873469222039_180213154/comments?access_token=180213154.f59def8.f888fe332f7c47e98bd20a44866ef0be

And what i want is get text between specific keyword given. So, from the example URL i want to get text between double quote and hashtags #title. So the result is -> **Sushi Homemade**

How to do this through PHP? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: <?php
$url       = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/375163873469222039_180213154/comments?access_token=180213154.f59def8.f888fe332f7c47e98bd20a44866ef0be";
$result  = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
?>

Comment: and how to extract text betwen specified keyword from that json?

Comment: use json decode and parse

Comment: Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple way

```
<?php
$json = '{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"created_time":"1358953338","text":"ciye koki sushi :))","from":{"username":"mayarahmanita","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_282786052_75sq_1357394407.jpg","id":"282786052","full_name":"Mayaa Rahmanita Hardianti"},"id":"375250258876255756"},{"created_time":"1358954810","text":"baguuus kan ada yg digoreng jg lho :-D","from":{"username":"realwahyuputra","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","id":"180213154","full_name":""},"id":"375262607376994013"},{"created_time":"1358960360","text":"mau dong nyoba :3","from":{"username":"mayarahmanita","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_282786052_75sq_1357394407.jpg","id":"282786052","full_name":"Mayaa Rahmanita Hardianti"},"id":"375309164881202914"},{"created_time":"1358960656","text":"makanya jgn lama2 di balinya :-[","from":{"username":"realwahyuputra","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","id":"180213154","full_name":""},"id":"375311649997934355"},{"created_time":"1388808291","text":"Sushi Homemade #title","from":{"username":"realwahyuputra","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","id":"180213154","full_name":""},"id":"625691760184610726"},{"created_time":"1388808305","text":"Rp50.000 #price","from":{"username":"realwahyuputra","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","id":"180213154","full_name":""},"id":"625691875997732786"}]}';

$arr = json_decode($json);

if(is_array($arr->data))  {       
    foreach($arr->data as $key=>$val){
        if(preg_match('/#title/', $val->text)){
            print preg_replace('/#title/', '', $val->text);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello kwelsan, how if i want to add more advanced filter to get value only when username:realwahyuputra. So, the value between #title and doublequote just extracted if the value of username is realwahyuputra. Could you help me :)

Comment: use this if condition: if(preg_match('/#title/', $val->text) && $val->from->username == 'realwahyuputra')

Comment: When i try to add it to instagram php api from https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API it returns PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). Here's the snippet: $comment = $instagram->getMediaComments($data->id);

foreach($comment->data as $key=>$val){
    if(preg_match('/#price/', $val->text)){
        $komen = preg_replace('/#price/', '', $val->text);
        break;
    }
}

Comment: Thanks, kwelsan:)
Could you help me to solve this problem too -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036170/creating-cache-file-from-instagram-api-class

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
<?php
$url       = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/375163873469222039_180213154/comments?access_token=180213154.f59def8.f888fe332f7c47e98bd20a44866ef0be";
$response  = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));
echo "<pre>";
foreach($response->data as $res) {
echo "Title".$res->text."\n";
}
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Titleciye koki sushi :))
Titlebaguuus kan ada yg digoreng jg lho :-D
Titlemau dong nyoba :3
Titlemakanya jgn lama2 di balinya :-[
TitleSushi Homemade #title
TitleRp50.000 #price
```

Comment: Thanks i combine your answer with another to fit what i want.
<?php
$json       = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/375163873469222039_180213154/comments?access_token=180213154.f59def8.f888fe332f7c47e98bd20a44866ef0be";
$arr  = json_decode(file_get_contents($json));
foreach($arr->data as $key=>$val){
    if(preg_match('/#price/', $val->text)){
        print preg_replace('/#price/', '', $val->text);
        break;
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of long-cut as I'm not familiar with regex so I've used string functions. Try it for different scenarios to see if it works well:

```
$str = '{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[{"created_time":"1358953338","text":"ciye koki sushi :))","from":{"username":"mayarahmanita","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_282786052_75sq_1357394407.jpg","id":"282786052","full_name":"Mayaa Rahmanita Hardianti"},"id":"375250258876255756"},{"created_time":"1358954810","text":"baguuus kan ada yg digoreng jg lho :-D","from":{"username":"realwahyuputra","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","id":"180213154","full_name":""},"id":"375262607376994013"},{"created_time":"1358960360","text":"mau dong nyoba :3","from":{"username":"mayarahmanita","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_282786052_75sq_1357394407.jpg","id":"282786052","full_name":"Mayaa Rahmanita Hardianti"},"id":"375309164881202914"},{"created_time":"1358960656","text":"makanya jgn lama2 di balinya :-[","from":{"username":"realwahyuputra","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","id":"180213154","full_name":""},"id":"375311649997934355"},{"created_time":"1388808291","text":"Sushi Homemade #title","from":{"username":"realwahyuputra","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","id":"180213154","full_name":""},"id":"625691760184610726"},{"created_time":"1388808305","text":"Rp50.000 #price","from":{"username":"realwahyuputra","profile_picture":"http:\/\/images.ak.instagram.com\/profiles\/profile_180213154_75sq_1359089013.jpg","id":"180213154","full_name":""},"id":"625691875997732786"}]}';

$substring = substr($str,0,strpos($str,'#title')); //returns from start of string till Sushi Homemade
$new2 = strrpos($substring,'"',-1);  //searches backwards and returns position of first " found
$new3 = substr($substring,$new2+1,strlen($substring));  //extracts string from " till end of string
echo trim($new3); //trimming forward and trailing space and displaying the needed string value
```