# Creating cache file from Instagram API Class

Tags: php, api, caching, instagram

I'm working with [Cosenary Instagram PHP API Classes](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) to fetch photos from instagram and try to create cache file to improve speed. Below is the snippet but it doesn't worked.

```
include('conf.php');
require 'bigflannel-instafeed/data/instagram.class.php';
// Initialize class
$instagram = new Instagram($accessToken);
$instagram->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$contents = $instagram->getUserMedia($userID,$settings['count']);
$cache = './instagram.json';
if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60 && filesize($cache) < 10){
// If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour and file size bigger than 10 bytes, use it
$instaData = file_get_contents($cache);
} else {
$instaData = file_get_contents($contents);
file_put_contents($cache,$instaData);
}
```

I checked file instagram.json just leave blank file with 0 byte size. 
I'm using code to create cache file from other question here [Caching Instagram API requests using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558078/caching-instagram-api-requests-using-php)

**-- Edit --**

If i replace $contents with json url, it works. But if i use $contents as part of API Class, it doesnt worked.

```
include('conf.php');
require 'bigflannel-instafeed/data/instagram.class.php';
// Initialize class
$instagram = new Instagram($accessToken);
$instagram->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$contents = json_encode($instagram->getUserMedia($userID,$settings['count']));
$cache = './instagram.json';
if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60 && filesize($cache) > 10){
// If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache));
} else {
$jsonData = json_decode((file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?access_token=180213154.f59def8.f888fe332f7c47e98bd20a44866ef0be&count=34")));
file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($jsonData));
}
```

Comment: Provide me full URL so that I can do something for you.

Comment: I edited the question above. Please check, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER

```
<?php
require 'instagram.class.php';

$cache = './cache.json';

if(file_exists($cache) && filemtime($cache) > time() - 60*60){
    // If a cache file exists, and it is newer than 1 hour, use it
    $response = json_decode(file_get_contents($cache),true); //Decode as an json array
} else {

    $instagram = new Instagram($accessToken);
    $instagram->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    $response = $instagram->getUserMedia($userID, $settings['count']);

    if($response){              
        file_put_contents($cache,json_encode($response)); //Save as json
    }     

}
echo "<pre>";
if(is_array($response)){
    foreach($response['data'] as $data){
            print_r($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: What i want is to make it works with Instagram PHP API Class from here: https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API/
 But i appreciated your answer:)

Comment: How to get all values, not limited to title, src, lat, lon because i want to fetch comment value too.

Comment: When i want to print/echo it with this code foreach ($response->data as $data) {
 It says Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Now you have array instead of object, so try  foreach ($response['data'] as $data) and try to use print_r sometime..

Comment: i've updated becomes foreach ($response['data'] as $data) {
 But still get the same problem. What must i do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44937/discussion-between-kwelsan-and-cutez7boyz)

Comment: you've made my day crazy! haha thank you so much kwelsan, glad to know you!

Comment: Hello kwelsan, now the code didn't work for json with size 140kb. Could you fix it for me? thanks.